# Cordova CLI building multiple applications

Tags: android, cordova

I have one project and I am building 2 apk's with the same codebase. For the most part they use the same plugins and js libraries.

I am using CLI for building apps in cordova 3.6. It's a little kludgy but works. I am trying to find a better way todo my builds. The issue I am facing is that I have to keey multiple copies of AndroidManafest.xml and keep swapping them out during my build process.

My process is something like this.

- cp www/config-app1.xml -> www/config.xml - these have different names
     and package structure
- cp platforms/android/AndroidManafest.xml
     -> platforms/android/AndroidManafest.xml.app2
- cp platforms/android/AndroidManafest.xml.app1 -> platforms/android/AndroidManafest.xml
- cp plugins/android.json.app1 -> plugins/android.json

I would have thought that my config.xml should change the name of the app in the AndroidManafest.xml and make adjustments to the android.json.

Any thoughts on a cleaner approach for performing these builds? I do recall that at one time in maybe version 3.5 that the apk would be generated with different names when I copied the app config.xml to the www  folder.

Comment: Can you just create 2 projects and make the changes in each one which would be minimal if they ae near identical, like one for tablet, one for mobiles, that way you are not copying manifests around

Comment: Haven't tried it by myself, but have a look at the platform- and plugin version management of cordova, maybe it helps: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/platform_plugin_versioning_ref_index.md.html#Platforms%20and%20Plugins%20Version%20Management

Comment: @Joerg -  Thats seems interesting, I will try a couple of passes at this, thanks.